# How to make resolvers run async

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am setting up java based graphQl App and find graphql-java-tools really convenient the problem though while itis pretty straight forward 
With graphql-java to make field resolvers Async  I couldn't Find a way to do it using graphql-java-tools

I tried

```
@Bean
    public ExecutionStrategy executionStrategy() {
        return new AsyncExecutionStrategy();
    }
```

Here resolvers I use in order to test

```
@Component
public class VideoResolver  implements GraphQLResolver<Video> {


     public Episode getEpisode(Video video){

        Episode result = new Episode();

        result.setTitle("episodeTitle");
        result.setUuid("EpisodeUuid");
        result.setBrand("episodeBrand");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public List<Images> getImages(Video video){

        Images image = new Images();
        image.setFileName("Image FileName1");
        List<Images> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
        imageList.add(image);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            System.out.println("Exxxxxxxxxx");
        }
        return imageList;
    }
}
```

Was assuming this should run in about 2 seconds and print two different streams but no it takes 4
and print it is all in one same stream